# The consequence of creating vast amounts of toxic waste

Tags: internal-consistency, vehicles

In my world cars operate on an inverse principle. Instead of fueling the car, the tank is preferably ran empty. As the car runs, viscous, toxic liquid builds up in the tank. When the tank is full, drivers go to the dump station to have their tanks emptied.

How the cars do this is not the focus of my question.  I'm investigating the consequences of this fluid.  Think of it this way, in the U.S. in 2018, an average of [391 million gallons of gasoline were used each day](https://www.eia.gov/tools/faqs/faq.php?id=23&t=10).  That means, in a country the size and population of the U.S. in my world, some 391 million gallons of this viscous, toxic fluid are being *created* each day.

The used sludge (at the moment) can be decomposed in an expensive process, stored. Those who decide to dump the sludge are heavily fined. It's a mix of hydrocarbons between 6 and 14 in length (85%), slightly irradiated lead (14.95%), and trace amounts of Helium (0.04%), and (platinum or xenon bubbles) (0.008%), depending on the model of engine used.

The substance gives off enough radiative energy to sustain a temperature about 0.05 Deg C above environmental, if stored in a spherical container, and is otherwise not dangerous for radiating properties. If the lead is extracted and refined, the radioactive energy is enough to increase the temp to about 2.1 deg C above the ambient, and poses a significant threat to those who inhabit near the metal.

What impact would this have on a country and society similar to the United States?

In an effort to avoid being too broad, I'm specifically interested in storage and the problems society would face relating to the accumulation of such a compound considering its volume and toxicity.

- The viscous, toxic fluid is a mix of hydrocarbons, slightly irradiated lead, and trace amounts of Helium, and (platinum or xenon bubbles).
- As I mentioned, the operation of the engine is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95182/discussion-on-question-by-tuskiomi-the-consequence-of-creating-vast-amounts-of-t).

Comment: You need to think about conservation of matter. Burning gasoline produces CO2 and H2O, which are used up by growing plants (just not fast enough). In your world, something has to produce the hydrocarbon that the car absorbs, and waste processing will probably have to return that hydrocarbon back to there.

Answer (score 3):

## Pump out

You're going through much the same process as yachts and narrow boats have to go through every few weeks, except for them it's not engine waste but rather human waste. They go to a service point, usually in a marina or similar, top up fuel and water, and pump out the waste tank.

Beyond that, nothing special, and no great change in the grand scheme of things.

Answer (score 2):

It is likely that getting rid of waste will be cheaper than getting gasoline in our world. Otherwise, there will be the same network of pumps, maybe slightly less dense as you can have a spare waste container.

It is possible that refineries will have their equivalent where waste is broken down into non-toxic components.

Otherwise, it will be a political problem where this waste eventually goes. The damage to environment is same or even greater as with oil, but since entry barrier is much lower, this will pay worse to the regions which host waste. See also "[garbage protests](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=garbage%20protests%20in%20russia&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)" in Russia underway

Comment: Do you think that because it's a liquid that storage will be any different?

Comment: I think that since the liquid is toxic so would be the discussion on where to stow it away.

Comment: Likely the damage will be a lot less since hydrocarbons can be recycled into other useful materials like plastic, medication, and asphalt.

Comment: Maybe there is a lot of residual tailings even after recycling. Such as acidic sludge laden with toxic elements.

Comment: The radioactive component will be concentrated as much as possible, and then buried. Radioactivity is not eternal, the more dangerous is the source of radioactivity, the faster it decays and becomes safe. So no problem here either.

Comment: There is a bitter spot when half-decay time is too long (let's say 30,000 years) yet impact is still high.

Answer (score 2):

### How vast are the vast amounts of toxic sludge?

The question is set in a world with bizarre physics, but nevertheless the question states that the setting is otherwise similar to the United States. Since magic can affect a lot of things but fortunately not geometry, we can estimate how vast are those famous vast amounts of toxic sludge.

Let's consider that cars have a comparable shape with ordinary mundane cars, so that the grille through which air enters the engine has an area of about 1 square meter. Which means that when the car travels 1 kilometer it will ingest about 1 thousand cubic meters of air. 1 thousand cubic meters of air weigh about 1 kilogram. Air contains about 0.04% carbon dioxide, so that kilogram of ingested air contains about 0.4 grams of carbon doxide, or about 0.1 grams of carbon.

Which means that the car produces about 0.1 grams of toxic sludge per kilometer travelled, or, if you prefer ye olde imperialle measurements, 2½ grains per mile. Assuming the waste receptable can hold 10 kilograms of waste, it will be filled in no less than 100,000 kilometers or 60,000 miles.

So every 100,000 kilomteres or 60,000 miles the owner must take the car to a service station and dispose of 10 kilograms of toxic waste. Since the toxic waste is stated to be a sort liquid mixture of hydrocarbons, that would be about 12 liters or 3½ gallons.

Doesn't seem to be all that complicated to me.

In the U.S.A. the total distance travelled is about 4 trillion vehicle-kilometers per year.

`4E12 * 1E-4 = 4E8` kilograms (or 40,000 metric tonnes) of toxic waste produced anually by magical vehicle engines in the the U.S.A. For comparison, the actual for real non-magical U.S.A. [produces some 20,000,000 tonnes of toxic waste per year](https://cfpub.epa.gov/roe/indicator_pdf.cfm?i=54). The contribution of the magical engines is some 0.2%.

Vast indeed.

Comment: Interesting...  though the question says 391,000,000 gallons per day..

Comment: @tuskiomi: Please indicate what is wrong with my calculations. The number in the question is in direct contradiction with basic geometry, and while I accept that magic can do a lot of wonderful things it cannot contradict geometry. (Hint: when an engine burns gasoline the products of combustion get to dissipate in the entire atmosphere. When an engine uses the air itself it cannot use more air than what is intercepted by the intake aperture. If you have ever seen an airliner engine now you know why it has that gigantic intake fan... Airliner engines use the air as reaction mass.)

Comment: Well the first error is the part where you don't use the given answer...

Answer (score 0):

Just carry the reversal to its logical conclusion, and have tankers collect the sludge and take it to derefineries where it’s made even worse, and then ship it to facilities around the world that pump it into the rock deep below the surface.